# Use icon instead of title in Tab layout

Tags: android-studio, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout which has a tab title. I want to use an icon instead of icon to be display. But im a little confuse on how can i implement that. Im trying to add a list of icons but i dont know where to put it. Thanks in advance :)

heres my code :

```
  public class City extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.city_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), City.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Info", "Hotels", "Restaurants", "Malls", "Events", "Tourist Spots"};
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Info();
            case 1:
                return new HotelPage();
            case 2:
                return new Restaurant();
            case 3:
                return new Mall();
            case 4:
                return new City_Events();
            case 5:
                return new Tourist_Spot();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(City.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_vtab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }
}
private int[] imageResId = {
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.password,
        R.drawable.back
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Jake Wharton's View pager](http://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) indicator here.

**Instructions**  (if u dont know how to add library in Android studio)

Download the zip file from github and extract it,
From your project in android studio,go to New-> import module-> choose library folder from the extracted file.

after adding library module to your project,
add this line under your dependencies in your gradle file

```
compile project(':library')
```

This is your City class code

```
public class City extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Info", "Hotels", "Restaurants", "Events" };
    private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            //arrage icons as per ur title content
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new CityAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    class CityAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
        public CityAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Info();
                case 1:
                    return new Info();
                case 2:
                    return new Info();
                case 3:
                    return new Info();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override public int getIconResId(int index) {
            return ICONS[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

**simple_tabs.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thats all, it should be working fine